# Caching issues - how to identifiy the offending server

Tags: cache-control

Hi
I replacing an existing website. One of the url to a page happens to match one of the url on the old site. I can see old content when I try accessing this url. Is it possible for to debug where this copy of the old site is coming from? I've already identified it's a server between me and our host because I get the same content on web based proxies and my android.

Also how would i get the cache updated?

Our host is Webfusion and our domain is with 123reg